# How to enter password without Keyboard on graphical login screen?

Tags: debian, login, lightdm

I am using **Debian desktop** for Lichee Pi and I am new this platform(linux).

After energizing, the graphical login screen appears.
But I don't have a real or virtual keyboard.

Can I enter this password from the command line? or can I skip this screen and switch to the desktop?

Comment: What is your DM ? Do you get some file named /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf ?

Comment: There is no gdm3 folder in /etc @MC68020

Comment: My DM is LightDM @MC68020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is named *autologin* and what you need is to update lightdm's configuration file : `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.
Edit this file and search for the following lines :

```
[Seat:*]
#autologin-user=
#autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Uncomment the two lines (remove the #) and add your user name at the end of the second.

[There are a couple of other settings you might want to consider.](https://wiki.debian.org/LightDM)

Comment: I think I corrupted this file a few minute ago. because file is empty. can i restore this? @MC68020

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales : You can try to download an all brand new one from github and review and adapt all the settings manually. https://github.com/Canonical/lightdm/blob/main/data/lightdm.conf . care about the version though. Or simply re-install the lightdm package.

Comment: i tried this, i wrote "root" for "#autologin-user" and saved. when i checked, two lines was uncommented and user was "root". But after reboot, login screen appeared . where could i go wrong? @MC68020

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales : Do you get a file named /etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin ?

Comment: Yes, this file is existed @MC68020

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales : Then comment out (add a # at beginning of the line) the following line : *auth   required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root*

Comment: but this line is not exist. This is exist under the "Allow access without authentication" : auth      required pam_permit.so @MC68020. Can i change this for "auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root" manually?